# Pandas: how to create a new column with the mean values of X columns by index

Tags: python, pandas

So, for example, if I have a table like this and I want to create a new column that tells me the mean values of Brazil and Argentina in each year, using the pandas function

```
mean()
```

| Date | Brazil | Argentina | Uruguay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1999 | 10 | 12 | 9 |
| 2000 | 11 | 15 | 10 |
| 2001 | 14 | 16 | 11 |
| 2002 | 13 | 16 | 12 |
| 2003 | 16 | 18 | 14 |
| 2004 | 17 | 20 | 13 |

How do I do it?

I was able to achive it by doing something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('latin_america.csv')

df.set_index('Date')

for x in df.index:
    df['New Column'] = (df['Brazil'] + df['Argentina'])/2
```

But i don't think it's optimal when working with more columns.

Comment: `df['New Column'] = df[['Brazil', 'Argentina']]).mean(axis=1)`